# ubuntu 14.04 LTS change dhclient lease file location

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, dhcp, dhclient

I cannot find how to change dhclient lease file location. By default (and currently) it is in `/var/lib/dhcp`, but I want this file to go to another place.

I did `ps ax | grep dhclient` and got this result:

```
 dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases eth0
```

where should I find dhclient invoke command and be able to change -lf parameter ?